# Oop concept for 3 different objects

Tags: oop

I have a supplier and a client object. So far so good.

I wish to send an email to the client, but to respect some good old fashion OOP concepts, it's not ok to add a send email method in supplier or client because the methods will break the SRP principle (among others). I should probably say: in both client and supplier I have some basic  CRUD operations.

So what is the solution? 
A SupplierClientEmail class with a static method even if this class will probably never be touch or used again ? How do you deal with such concepts in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to keep a record of the email?  If not, then you don't really need an object for it.  You could have an `EmailService` that has a method `sendEmail(client, supplier)` or whatever makes sense.

If you do need to keep track of emails, for example storing some sort of marker in the database to show an email was sent, you can have an `Email` class that has a reference to both client and supplier, with info like `dateSent` and any other info you need.  That way you can always go back and see what email was sent to which client/suppliers.  In this scheme `Email` knows about client and supplier, but those classes don't know about email.

Comment: I don't need to keep track but in the end EmailService will have a sendEmail method for client and supplier , then a sendEmail2 for a client and a product and so on, isn't this new class predisposed to changes ?

Comment: @danip, yes that's true, but that's true regardless if you don't know what email operations you will need to support.  and it wouldn't be `sendEmail2`, it should be named appropriately, e.g. `sendClientProductEmail` and `sendClientSupplierEmail`, etc...

Answer (score 0):

If it truly is a method you will use once here, never again, and only with the supplier objects, it would only make sense to include it here as a method.  In my personal opinion, a smattering of single-method classes is much more confusing and unwieldly than a simple addition of a private method.

Another option would be something like an EmailHelper class, that you would then throw this method into, as well as any other email-related loosely-fitting methods.